# How to get a dataframe using sample in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to get some samples based on the following criteria

```html
  

  df1 <- sample(10:100,100000,replace = TRUE)
    df <- data.frame(sample.size = c(10,20))
    df <- data.frame(sample.size = rep(c(10,20), times = rep(2,2)))
    samples <- lapply(df$sample.size, function (x) {sample(df1, x)})
```

This gives me a list of two samples of the intended sample sizes.  Now I want to generate a data frame as follows:

```html
sample  Group   value
1   10  x
1   10  x
1   10  x
1   10  x
1   10  x
1   10  x
1   10  x
1   10  x
1   10  x
1   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
2   10  x
.    .  .
```

Attempting is to convert list to dataframe, but does not help.

```html
convert<-  as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(samples), nrow=length(unlist(samples[1]))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
merge(cbind(ind = seq(nrow(df)), df), stack(setNames(samples, seq_along(samples))))
  ind sample.size values
1    1          10     14
2    1          10     64
3    1          10     77
4    1          10     73
5    1          10    100
6    1          10     78
7    1          10     23
8    1          10     12
9    1          10     86
10   1          10    100
11   2          10     26
12   2          10     98
13   2          10     86
14   2          10     67
15   2          10     38
16   2          10     60
17   2          10     12
 :
 :
```

with tidyverse this could be reduced to:

```
map_df(samples, ~data.frame(Group = length(.x), value=.x), .id = 'sample')
```

Comment: @ Onyambu Very much thanks indeed, great codes +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is one base R option -

```
do.call(rbind, 
        Map(cbind.data.frame, 
            sample = seq_along(samples), Group = df$sample.size, value = samples
        )
)

#   sample Group value
#1       1    10    61
#2       1    10    14
#3       1    10    90
#4       1    10    13
#5       1    10    10
#6       1    10    98
#7       1    10    52
#8       1    10    72
#9       1    10    69
#10      1    10    92
#11      2    10    90
#12      2    10    49
#13      2    10    60
#...
#...
```